# Can I use a satellite resource assembly for one language in the OS for another language simply by changing the name of the folder the dll appears in?

Tags: .net, localization, internationalization, satellite-assembly

If I compile a .NET satellite assembly with localised resources, does the assembly itself know which language it is for, or is this implied in the folder in which it appears?

If I decide to create a localised assembly where all strings are enclosed by '@' symbols for testing if all of my app is localised and then install that on an EN-GB OS in an 'en' sub folder and load the app up and I see all my symbols enclosed by '@' signs, can I then use the same assembly on a German OS, but put it in a 'de' subfolder and expect it to still localise the app?  Or is there something in the assembly compilation which embeds the locale that the assembly and so even if it finds it in the right place it will not load it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satellite assemblies contain culture information in file header. So the answer to your question is simply no, you cannot just rename the folder.